# Why my C++ class does not work when I split it into multiple files?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am trying to learn C++ classes for the first time. I managed to make simple class into one file as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Myclass {
    public:
        Myclass(int number);
        void print_myclass();

    private:
        int number_;
};

Myclass::Myclass(int number):
    number_(number) {
    }

void Myclass::print_myclass(){
    cout << number_ << endl;
}


int main() {

    Myclass myclass(13);
    myclass.print_myclass();

}
```

However when I try to split it into multiple files, as seems to be the practice, it simply will not work. VSCode will not show me any errors, but when compiling it gives me this:

[image]

Here is the code with seperated class:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.hh"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Myclass myclass(13);
    myclass.print_myclass();

}
```

myclass.hh

```
class Myclass {
    public:
        Myclass(int number);
        void print_myclass();

    private:
        int number_;
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.hh"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Myclass::Myclass(int number):
    number_(number) {
    }

void Myclass::print_myclass(){
    cout << number_ << endl;
}
```

I am not sure if this is a problem with the code or how this thing is complied, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your build task is failing with some errors. See the details there. My guess? That `cout` should be `std::cout`, `endl` -> `std::endl`.

Comment: you have to compile both source files and then link them together. I suggest you to learn this on the console by directly invoking the compiler before you learn how to configure your IDE. IDEs do a good job at hiding the details from you, but if you don't know the details it can be difficult to configure it correctly

Comment: @TanveerBadar That is correct. IDE did not give me this error before, but it noticed it now for whatever reason. I added `using namespace std` into that file. However otherwise this did not fix the error window when compiling.

Comment: What you’re (probably) trying to achieve here is to build two modules and then link them together. You need to configure your build environment accordingly. Also, showing a dialog box of some sort makes no sense. Looking at the actual error message would help much more. (Last but not least, `using namespace std;` is a troublesome antipattern; just don’t do that.)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks a lot! Compiling it from terminal did work and the binary ran with no problems or errors. I am still keen on learning to do this from IDE also, I definitely also want to know the CLI implementation.